# Using TFS API to get work items by a field instead of ID

Tags: api, tfs

I want to use the TFS API to get a workitem, but it only seems to support getting a workitem by providing an ID field.

I'm making a web portal in which a general account has to find a work item by for example the assigned/area field/project name.

I can't find any documentation on the official page, is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using VSTS or some of the newer versions of TFS, you can use the WIQL REST API https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/wiql
There are also code samples on how to use it here https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-restapi-samplecode/commit/a27a0c48b81f1ba74ea638e8bae46072f645e8af

Comment: I found out that I can indeed use WIQL to send queries in with http, or use http to "contact" stored queries in TFS!

Answer (score 0):

Getting an work item only by a field (other than Id) will not you guarantee the uniqueness of that work item. It's possible to have more work items with that value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
Wiql wiql = new Wiql()
    {
        Query = "Select [State], [Title] " +
                "From WorkItems " +
                "Where [Work Item Type] = 'Bug' " +
                "And [System.TeamProject] = '" + project + "' " +
                "And [System.State] <> 'Closed' " +
                "Order By [State] Asc, [Changed Date] Desc"
    };
//create instance of work item tracking http client
using (WorkItemTrackingHttpClient workItemTrackingHttpClient = new WorkItemTrackingHttpClient(uri, credentials))
{
    //execute the query to get the list of work items in the results
    WorkItemQueryResult workItemQueryResult = workItemTrackingHttpClient.QueryByWiqlAsync(wiql).Result;
}
```